# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 14

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I am trying to connect to sql server database .

I wrote vb.NET code to connect to database using bellow con. string:

```
"Server=ABOODPC\aboodsrvr; Database=testDB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

when converting the code into c# , I get the problem as shown in the title .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `\a` is being seen as an escape sequence (for "alert", U+007). The simplest approach is to use a verbatim string literal instead:

```
@"Server=ABOODPC\aboodsrvr; Database=testDB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Alternatively, just double the backslash:

```
"Server=ABOODPC\\aboodsrvr; Database=testDB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

... or stop storing your connection string directly in your source code at all, of course...

Comment: The easiest standard way to not store your connection string in your source code would be to add a `connectionStrings` element to your app.config (accessible via `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString`).  If you're not already accustomed to using an app.config in your app, it's something you should learn how to do.